# how to pass a json String to a url using Flask

Tags: python, json, flask, jsonify

I did create a machine learning model using Pytorch which i want to use as a webservice using Flask. The problem is that i don't understand how i can pass a json-String to the url. Below is my code that I wrote to do some tryouts with my model and Flask:

```
from modelLoader import Model
from imageLoader import Img
import os
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)
classes = ["dummy-image", "product-image"]
model_path = os.path.join("data", "models", "model1709", "model1709")
image_path = os.path.join("data", "images", "dummy_images")
m1 = Model(model_path, classes, "cpu")

@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def predict():
    # case for handle json
    input_data = request.get_json()['url']
    if isinstance(input_data, list):
        for elem in input_data:
            img_elem = Img(url=elem)
            res = img_elem.get_prediction(m1)
        return jsonify({"type": "bulk_upload"})
    img_inpdata = Img(url=input_data)
    res, info = img_inpdata.get_prediction(m1)
    return jsonify({input_data: res, "info": str(info)})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This would be a request that I want to make using this code:

```
POST http://192.168.178.13:5000/predict HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json

{
    "url" : "https://socialistmodernism.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/placeholder-image.png"
}
```

How exactly can I get the prediction for the image inside the json-string, by passing this json-string to the application?

---

Here the two classes model and imageLoader for completeness:

```
from torch import argmax, device, load, nn

class Model:
    def __init__(self, path, class_list=None, dvc=None):
        if class_list is None:
            class_list = [0, 1]
        if dvc is None:
            dvc = 'cpu'
        self.class_list = class_list 
        self.model = load(path, map_location=device(dvc))
        num_ftrs = self.model.fc.in_features                  
        self.model.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, len(class_list))  
        self.model.eval()
```

---

```
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import io
from PIL import Image
from torch import argmax, device, load, nn
import requests

class Img:
    def __init__(self, url=None, image=None, image_bytes=None):
        if url:
            img = Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw)
            img_byte_arr = io.BytesIO()
            img.save(img_byte_arr, format=img.format)
            self.image_bytes = img_byte_arr.getvalue()
        elif image:
            f = image.read()
            self.image_bytes = bytearray(f)
        elif image_bytes:
            self.image_bytes = image_bytes

    def transform_image(self):
        data_transforms = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
                                              transforms.CenterCrop(
                                                  224), transforms.ToTensor(),
                                              transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224,
                                                                                           0.225])])
        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(self.image_bytes)).convert('RGB')
        return data_transforms(image).unsqueeze(0)

    def get_prediction(self, model):
        tensor = self.transform_image()
        output = (model.model(tensor))
        sm = nn.Softmax(output)
        best = output.argmax().item()
        return model.class_list[best], sm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do a POST request directly from the browser URL box. There are many applications to test your API and my favorite one is [postman](https://www.postman.com/). You can also use the curl command tool.

If you want to use the browser URL box only, then consider using the GET request. The format of GET request is <URL>?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2. You can access the value of the parameter in flask using the request module. For example, if your service is at http://192.168.178.13:5000/predict. You can send it as http://192.168.178.13:5000/predict?url=your-url. And you can fetch it in flask as

```
from flask import request
my_url = request.args.get("url")
```